# Seurat Violin Plot: Why do dots align in one row?

Tags: scrnaseq, seurat

I am analyzing a rather small scRNAseq dataset (39797 features across 3522 samples) and I have observed that dots in the violin plot are plotted in one line next to each other rather than in a cloud of dots (see plot below):

[image]

I am just wonndering what the reason might be for this?

I have followed the Integration and Label Transfer tutorial using SCTransform (https://satijalab.org/seurat/v3.1/integration.html). After the integration process I switched back to the SCT assay, which should contain the normalized counts. For plotting I used the following command:
VlnPlot(..., assay = "SCT", slot = "data"), again specifying to use the normalized counts.

Can someone explain me why this is the case?

Thank you already in advance!

Answer (score 1):

That is because SCTransform (mostly) outputs discrete values, you can check the @slot of your Seurat object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!Do you know why this is mostly for lower expression values?

Comment: It's log-scaled.